# How to add javadoc for ecpliselink 1.x

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipselink

[alt text http://filaty.com/i/1005/60197/Screenshot.png](http://filaty.com/i/1005/60197/Screenshot.png)

As It appears in the image, I cannot add the javadoc for eclipselink 1.1.x that already bundled with eclipse.
So, Is there any workaround?